# Is there any way to have a comment inside a tag

Tags: vue.js

I know that we can put a comment in vuejs template using html comments:

```
<div>
  <!-- comment -->
</div>
```

But I wonder is there a way to put a comment in between opening and closing angle characters (inside tag):

```
<button
  class=""
  :prop-a=""
  <!-- this comment is invalid -->
  :prop-b=""
>
</button>
```

Comment: This isn't possible.